# What event should be used for handling drag and drop of rows in dojo dgrid?

Tags: javascript, events, drag-and-drop, dojo, dgrid

I have a [dojo dgrid with DnD support](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v1.1.0/doc/components/extensions/DnD.md). I want to handle the event when user drags and drops rows of the grid. I was not able to find a list of all events that are supported by dgrid.

I am able to work with other events listed in the [Working with Events section](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v1.1.0/doc/usage/Working-with-Events.md) such as

`grid.on('.dgrid-header .dgrid-cell:click', function (event) {}`

however, I cannot find the name of the event to be used for drag&drop.

What is the name of this event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the link shared by you (Working with Events section), `dgrid` does not have any events related to dnd.

However, the dndSource which is extension of `dojo/dnd/source` has a set of event which you can use to listen.

```
on(grid1.dndSource, "Drop", function(){
    //do something
});
```

You could also use the `dojo/topic` to listen to some of the topics published by the dnd.Manager.

```
topic.subscribe("/dnd/drop", function(){
    //do something
});
```

Below are the list of topic you can listen:

- /dnd/source/over
- /dnd/start
- /dnd/drop/before
- /dnd/drop
- /dnd/cancel

Comment: Awesome, the first version works fine, I'll stick to this one. Can you please provide the URL where you got the list of events name such as `"Drop"`? Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to find all the event in the dojo api documentation. http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojo/dnd/Source